# What are the advatages of IPMI when matched against regular SSH?

Tags: networking, ssl, ipmi, ipmitool, bmc

How does IPMI differ from regular user-to-host SSH? From what I know, SSH is simply access to the terminal of the head node and IPMI is linked to the actual hardware of the head node, but that is the limit of my knowledge.

Does the Supermicro IPMI Tool CLI allow access to the terminal on the head node?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question makes no sense. This is like what is the difference between a car and an answering machine.

SSL is a transport level security.

IPMI is a remote control protocol. It may, btw., utilize SSL to protect the data in transit.

When was the last time you used SSL directly to install an operating system? Which part of the SSL standard allows you to turn a computer on or off?

> Does the Supermicro IPMI Tool CLI allow access to the terminal on the head 
>   node?

Consider occcasionally reading documentation. You have a lot of lacks of fundamentals that are clear aftethe first pages.

> From what I know, SSL is simply access to the terminal of the head node and 
>   IPMI is linked to the actual hardware of the head node, but that is
>   all.

"that is all" is sceaming ignorant. From what I know a rocket just burns fuel and "that is all". When you ahve to manage computers in a remove location or do not want to spend all day in data center environments (loud, cold) and are responsible for a lot of computes, "that is all" is exactly what you need. In fact "that is all" (access to the actual hardware) is what SSL is not providing and what IPMI is made for.

Comment: There is a little confusion here, I have edited the question which might make it clearer. By "that is all" I meant that is all I know :P Additionally, I wrote SSL instead of SSH. Apologies :)

Comment: Well, you got an answer for the question you did ask, not the question you wanted to ask. Live with it - I personally find rewriting the question after having an answer to a significant degree extremely arrogant and unfriendly.

Comment: Yep, I understand. I don't expect you in any way to change your answer :). Besides, it was a well written answer and I got what I needed through it. Thank you once again